# symfony can't build schema (propel)

Tags: symfony, propel, phing

I've been trying symfony 1.2.12, using xampp 3.1.0 over windows XP (the jobeet tutorial). When I try to run *php symfony propel:build-schema* I've got the following error (over and over):

Propel Running "reverse" phing task

[taskdef] Error importing propel/phing/PropelDataModelTemplateTask.php

[phing] Error reading project file [Wrapped: Error importing propel/phing/PropelDataModelTemplateTask.php]

Some problems ocurred when executing the task: If the exception is not clear enough read the output.

(I've checked the phing version and it's 2.5.0, the latest available.)

I've searched for the PropelDataModelTemplateTask.php and is not in the project (the entire path doesn't exists!). I've created another symfony project and the file isn't there either. It looks like it's not included whit the symfony-1.2.12.tgz.

Is there something wrong within this version or should I install or update any extra component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never used symfony1, but maybe you need to install `propel` bundle.

Comment: Can't help with the problem Symfony 1.2 is extremely old.  Move to S2.3.  Your tutorial won't be much help but at least you can get support.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. I'm taking my first steps with symfony, and I'm not aware of the differences. Anyway, I can't make it work in any 1.x versions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Huge difference between S1 and S2.  No point in wasting any time at all on S1 unless you need to maintain legacy apps.  And even then you should be on S1.4.  Moving to S2 is the right way to go.